# Upload Photos using Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

I've searched the web far & wide, to no avail. All I want to do is take a picture on my phone and have it attached to any object in my Salesforce org. It needs to play well with Salesforce1. I don't need fancy editing or effects. The only AppExchange option I found had a lot of custom object/tab overhead.(SharinPix) Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can always do that from the Salesforce app. There's an action available named as "File" and that it allows you to take a photo/video or access your album on the phone. As soon as you upload one, the file gets added to the "Notes & Attachment" for the record.

Below is the screenshot from Salesforce for iOS.

[image]